# storing a string into 2D array

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, vector

```
  a   b
00001 3
00002 2
00003 1 4
00004 2 4 5
00005 1 2
00006 1 2 4
00007 2 5
00008 3 4 5
00009 3 4 5
00010 2 3
```

This is my data, I open it in C++ with getline and I wish to split them into a 2D vector. wish to have a 10*2 array which first column is a and second column is b. What should I do?

This is my code

```
int row = 0;
int column = 2;
string line;
vector<vector<string>>info;
ifstream data("C:\\01_test.txt");
while (getline(data, line))
{

    row++;
}
data.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do sth like that:

```
string line;
int main(){
 vector<vector<string> > info;
 ifstream data("C:\\01_test.txt");
 static int cnt=0;
 while(getline(data, line)){
  istringstream iss(line);
  info.push_back(vector<string>());
  copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(info[cnt]));
  cnt++;
 }
};
```

if you wanna use vector of int use some function to change string to int like atoi.

Comment: 00001 3

00002 2

00003 1 

00004 2 

00005 1 

00006 1 

00007 2

00008 3 

00009 3 

00010 2 

this is the output but the it lost some of data

Comment: Can You show me complete snipet of Youre code? My output: 00001, 3, 00002, 2, 00003, 1, 4, 00004, 2, 4, 5, 00005, 1, 2, 00006, 1, 2, 4, 00007, 2, 5, 00008, 3, 4, 5, 00009, 3, 4, 5, 00010, 2, 3,

Comment: string line;
 vector<vector<string>>info;
 ifstream data("C:\\01_test.txt");
 static int cnt = 0;
 while (getline(data, line))
 {
  istringstream iss(line);
  info.push_back(vector<string>());
  copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(info[cnt]));
  cnt++;
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
   cout << info[i][j]<<" ";
  cout << endl;
 }
 
 data.close();

Comment: You are printing only 2 elems each time for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) cout << info[i][j]<<" "; Try printing by:  for(int i=0; i<info.size(); ++i)
 {
 copy(info[i].begin(), info[i].end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
 }

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. actually I am wanting a 10*2 array where first column is 00001 and second column is 3

Comment: Oh I see just change copy loop put first elem in as 1 elem of vector and rest concat to some tmp string and add as second

Comment: can you show me the actual code? sorry I cant understand what you said

Comment: int main(){
string line; vector<vector<string> > info;
ifstream data("in");
 static int cnt = 0;
 while (getline(data, line)) {
  istringstream iss(line);
  ostringstream oss;
  string tmp;
  info.push_back(vector<string>());
  iss >> tmp;
  info[cnt].push_back(tmp);
  oss << iss.rdbuf();
 string second(oss.str());
  info[cnt].push_back(second);
++cnt;
 }
 for(int i=0; i<info.size(); ++i)
 {
 copy(info[i].begin(), info[i].end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
cout<<endl;
 }

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/#example). If you look at the example in the link, it should be quite obvious.

Comment: sorry, I am new in programming can you help write an example?

Comment: it just show me the left handside, how about the right handside?